# Cubemap does not rotate in Gameview but rotates in device in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have created cubemap in Unity.

I am able to see complete 360 by rotating it on Device.
However, when I try to rotate it in Gameview using mouse, nothing happens.

In my Game view cube map rotate using below code.but I want to rotate cube map using mouse pointer.which code should I write Instead of below code to rotate cube map using mouse pointer.?

```
Vector3 lerpedRotation = new Vector3 ();
    Vector3 userInput = new Vector3 ();
    Vector3 regularRotation = new Vector3 ();

regularRotation.y += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * -0.05f;
                regularRotation.x += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * 0.05f;
                if(textLeftTitle!=null && Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X")<280*wdpi){          lerpedRotation.y = 0;
                    lerpedRotation.x = 0;
                }
```

I am newbie to Unity.
Hence need your guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code you use to rotate the cubemap?

Comment: Cubemap rotate using skybox functionality.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your code is compatible with mouse rotation? If you don't post relevant parts of the code, it is quite likely that you are not getting any help here.